# How to run Admob Ads in Between List

Tags: android, interstitial, admob

I am devoloping an Android app with recycler view.The app shows wallpapers.Every wallpaper is as an recycler view item. The item will be gullscreen.If we Swipe next wallpaper will come.Can I place admob interstitial ads in Between wallpapers like when I swipe sometimes the ads will come instead of walpaper.please help.

Comment: i think you cannot set interstitial ads between list

Comment: you may can check current adapter position and show an interstetial ad but it won't be a part of list . if You want it to be part of list you will find some luck with native ads